# Can I reproduce Scala's behavior for ==?

Tags: scala, null, equals

In Programming in Scala, I can read that the `==` operator behaves as if it was defined like this:

```
final def == (that: Any): Boolean = if (null eq this) {null eq that} else {this equals that}
```

But there must actually be compiler magic to avoid null pointer exceptions, right? Is there any way for me to replicate this behavior with pure Scala; i.e., have an operator/method return one thing if the receiver is null and another one if it isn't? What I mean is an actual implementation of `null eq this`.

I suppose I can write a "pimp" and then define the method on the wrapper class, but is there a more direct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. <strike>As far as I know there is no magic for nulls.</strike> (see Update)

I think the best you can do, is to wrap any object to option, so that you can use bunch of useful stuff from it:

```
implicit def toOption[T](target: T) = Option(target)

val q: String = null
val q1: String = "string"

println(q getOrElse "null") // prints: null
println(q1  getOrElse "null") // prints: string
```

### Update

I found this document:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.7/scala/Null.html

According to it:

> Class Null is - together with class Nothing - at the bottom of the Scala type hierarchy.

So even `null` has methods inherited from `AnyRef` like `eq`, `==`, etc... And you also can use them:

```
val q: String = null
val q1: String = "string"

println(null eq q) // prints: true
println(null eq q1) // prints: false
```

Comment: There has to be some magic: try to define a method similar to == and call it on a `null` pointer: you get a `NullPointerException`. With == you don't.

Comment: @JPP: see update. yeah, it turns to be some kind of magic there... the same kind of magic as with `Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Indeed there's some magic — so I can't reproduce it, right?

Comment: @JPP: I don't think so. But you can always write your [compiller plugin](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/140) :)

Comment: A compiler plugin to get rid of null somehow.

Comment: @Monkey: Yeah, it would be great! @JPP, We encourage you to write such plugin - we all would be eternally grateful to you for this!... but for the moment being we all should try to use `Option` more...

Answer (score 2):

"null" is the only instance of a trait called Null - so it's just a normal object, no magic to invoke ==

You should definitely check out Option and do everything you can to keep nulls out of your code :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a normal object. Trait Null inherits hashCode from AnyRef, right? But try calling hashCode on null: NPE. So eq, == and others need compiler magic.

Comment: NPE doesn't suggest magic to me - an implementation of hashCode on a Null class should throw NPE.  If hashCode didn't exist, it would be a compile error, not an NPE.

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic for nulls, but scala does have *some* magic for making equality symmetric for numbers.
The trick is to extend the `ScalaNumber` trait...

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/6387

**update**

Just to clarify that a bit... This means that if you write `a == b` and `b` derives from `ScalaNumber` or (I believe) is an `AnyVal`, then the compiler will test instead for `b == a`.

Not only does this resolve the `null` situation, but it also makes things a lot easier if you want to compare a primitive to some other type that can be viewed as a number, but for which an implicit conversion would be recklessly unsafe.  This is the approach used with e.g. BigInteger.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be any way to do this without special casing the null case. Java won't allow a method to be called if the object is null. This compared to a language like python where None is a proper object. I think the best thing to do is try and ignore the fact that null exists.

Useing an implicit to simulate ==

```
class Equals2(v:AnyRef){
  def ===(that:AnyRef) =  if(v eq null) {that eq null }else {v equals that}
}
implicit def equals2(v:AnyRef) = new Equals2(v)
```

Unfortunately the following doesn't work as null is not a subclass of AnyRef

```
null === "Something"
```

Comment: I concur. Even `implicit def equals2(v:Null) = new Equals2(v)` doesn't work. I'm not sure why. I guess `null` just can't be implicitly converted. Though explictly calling the `equals2` function will work fine, even without the `equals2(v:Null)` overload.

Answer (score 1):

`null` is the only instance of `Null` and is therefore -- in Scala -- a full object.

If you define your function in the spirit as you posted above in class `A`, all you have to do is to provide an implicit conversion from `Null` to `A` that maps `null` to some dummy instance.

Comment: OK. So, can't do it without implicit conversion. That's all I needed to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Option.

```
scala> Option("a")
res0: Option[java.lang.String] = Some(a)

scala> Option(null)
res1: Option[Null] = None
```

Comment: I wanted to define a method on y custom class of mine, where I can implement a check of the type `this eq null` without a NPE.

Comment: To be clear, this eq null will never cause a null pointer exception.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are looking for?